# Why can't I move the camera as freely as I can navigate in the 3D View?

Tags: interface, camera, navigation

Just switched from maya to blender and as you can assume, I'm having some troubles. I can figure out the program just fine, but I want to know the reason why the render camera is designed with such navigation restrictions? Why not give it the same movability as the viewport? And is there a way I can change this?

Comment: Type "N" to get the right side panel open, go to View > View > View Lock > Lock Camera to view

Answer (score 0):

The camera has absolutely no restrictions whatsoever. Normally you can move it just like you can move any object with your `Move`, `Rotate` and `Scale` tools.

If you want something like a first-person-mode expand the side panel on the right edge of your 3D-view (or hit the `N`-key on your keyboard) and then go to the tab `View`->`View Lock` and toggle `Lock Camera to View`. This will "bind" the camera to your viewport perspective.

Once you're happy with your camera position un-toggle the option to move freely again, without accidentally displacing your camera.